# How to copy huge amount of data from one Oracle database to another with good performance

Tags: java, sql, performance, oracle

I need to copy about 50 millions of rows with joins among 3 4 tables from one Oracle db to another into a single table. This is a repeating process happening from time to time. I copy only active data (meaning that there's some outdated archived data that not needed any more). We havea special java service which does this procedure via JDBC which is too slow for our needs.

Comment: 50 million rows might be too slow for your needs no matter what method you use.  How long is it taking now?

Comment: You need to find the root cause of this problem. Is it running the query of extracting the data via JDBC?

Comment: Our service retrieves data from 1 database, translates it into a specific format, packs to BLOB and saves into a table of another database. The issue is that it is too slow on such a volume. The reason to pack is data compression of unsearchable fields. Such a field has over 100 columns inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Transportable Modules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31080_01/doc/owb.102/b28223/ref_trans_mod.htm)

> The fundamental functionality of a Transportable Module is to copy a
>   group of related database objects from one database to another using
>   the fastest possible mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataPump utility available in Oracle 10g onwards. It gives you the capability to use direct path export. To know more, here is the link -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm